# Cronjob issue. Doesn't recognize variable

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

Works:

```
php -q /home/site/public_html/cron/file.php
```

Doesn't work:

```
php -q /home/site/public_html/cron/file.php?variable=1
```

Any suggestions? I need to send the variable as $_GET (or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it something like this

```
curl http://hostname/cron/file.php?variable=1
```

and in the file.php you will be managing the code to get the $_GET[variable]

this woould behave as a simple browser call but only in your shell/terminal

Hope this helps

Comment: no but in this case the variable will be treated as a GET variable by your file.php script...

Answer (score 1):

Command Line arguments are passed in [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) instead of the normal `$_GET`/`$_POST`-Arrays

Of course this does not work with URI-style parameters (that `?variable=1`-part). So you have to call it like: `php -q /path/to/script.php 1`.

As an alternative you could use [`getopt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php):

```
<?php
$shortopts  = implode("", array(
    "v:"
));

$longopts  = array(
    "variable:",     // Required value
);


$options = getopt($shortopts, $longopts);
var_dump($options);
```

And call it like `php -q /path/to/script.php --variable=1`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to work around this (assuming public_html, is, well, public WWW), is to have cron call wget or curl to access the PHP file, so URL variables are processed as normal.

Answer (score -1):

-q means no head, so there is no space for the get-fields i assume, at least i hope so :D

Greetz